# Installing Curl IDE/RTE on AMD processors

Tags: ide, amd-processor, curl-language

Trying to move my development environment to Linux. And new to Curl. Can't get it to install the IDE & RTE packages on an AMD HP PC running Ubuntu x64. I tried to install the Debian package via the package installer and get "Error: Wrong architecture - i386". Tried using the  --force-architecture switch but it errors out.

I'm assuming Curl IDE will just run under Intel processors? Anyone have any luck with this issue and can advise?

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I ran linux, but try looking for the x64 version. There are also x64 to x86 compatibility libraries available that should make 32 bit programs work for most situations.

The [ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/) are a much better place for this question, however.